# .include? within an if statement not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, random, while-loop

I'm trying to populate an array in ruby with unique random numbers between 0 and 4.  I'm trying to use an if statement on a.include? but it is not working. Can anyone help me understand why the statement `if numbers.include?(new_array_num) == false` doesn't seem to be working? Also, I'm trying to make this work without the .shuffle method. Thanks!

```
num = 5
counter = 5
numbers = []

while counter >= 0 
    new_array_num = rand(num)
    if numbers.include?(new_array_num) == false
        numbers.push new_array_num
        counter -= 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand(num)` is giving you a result from 0-4. That's 5 values: 0,1,2,3,4.  You're trying to put a value in at counter values 5,4,3,2,1,0. There aren't enough values from rand to make that work. Try `counter > 0` or perhaps better yet:

```
[0,1,2,3,4].shuffle
# => [3, 2, 4, 0, 1]
```

Comment: AH ha. I see now. Too many slots in the array, not enough numbers to go in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
while counter >= 0
```

needs to be

```
while counter > 0
```

Your loop is filling up with every possible random number in range, and you're asking it for one more, so you loop can never end.

If your intent is to produce a randomly sorted array of all numbers between 1 and x, use `(1..x).to_a.shuffle`

Comment: +1 for actually explaining where OP's problem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest this:

```
num = 5
counter = 5
numbers = []

while numbers.count < counter
  random = rand(num)
  numbers << random unless numbers.include?(random)
end

puts numbers
```

Update.

I liked the idea of using shuffle, and if you want it dynamic you can use:

```
n = 5
(0..n).to_a.shuffle
# => [2, 1, 4, 0, 5]
```

Comment: this looks like an elegant solution. Learned some new syntax too. Thanks Arthur!